# How to properly exit ipdb interactive console in Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: debugging, jupyter-notebook, ipdb

[image: Jupyter Notebook]

Hi, what's the proper way to exit ipdb interactive console running in a Jupyter Notebook cell? I've tried exit, quit, Ctrl-Z, Ctrl-C, Ctrl-D (throws up the bookmark request in chrome)

Update:
Tried sys.exit(), it killed the kernel of the notebook. How can we just exit the interactive shell without affecting the notebook?

Answer (score 2):

In ipdb in interactive mode I exit using: `from sys import exit; exit()`

Answer (score -2):

type in `q` to "quit". It works just like regular debug console in terminal

Comment: Doesn't work once you've entered `interactive` mode.

Comment: Worked for me after entering interactive mode. Using JupyterLab 4.0.8